# A problem about an equation of a system of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Please, can you help me at this problem: determine the equation of the system of vectors

$$U_1 =\{ x_1,x_2,x_3 \}$$

where:

$$x_1=(2,1,2)$$
$$x_2=(-1,0,1)$$
$$x_3=(1,1,3)$$

This is not linear independent,and I don't know how to identify the equation of it.

I thank you very much for your understanding and I wait forward your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Start from $$a x_1 + b x_2 + c x_3 = (0,0,0)$$

Solve for $a$, $b$ and $c$

Answer (score 0):

The linear dependence relation $ax_1 + bx_2 +cx_3 = 0$ can be expressed using a matrix by placing the vectors as columns:
$$\begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\\ 2 & 1 & 3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Row-reducing, we find that $a = b = -c$, so we have (for instance) the relation $x_1 + x_2 - x_3 = 0$.